# Is It Possible to copy/paste mongodb database files from 32bit(OS) to 64bit(OS) both on 64bit Architecture and go on?

Tags: linux, mongodb, 64-bit, 32-bit

As the subject relates, is it possible without future issues?.
Basically i'm posting this thread for future references, so people can watch the scenario.
What are the reasons of mongodb being limited to 2Gb?.
Can you please point out references so noobs like me can learn the deeps?.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy data files from 32 bit to 64 bit and this will be fine. Reason for limitation of file size on 32 bit is because of limitations of 32 bit memory address space.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the reasons of mongodb being limited to 2Gb?

Because it uses memory mapped files, see the [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#what-are-the-limitations-of-32-bit-versions-of-mongodb).